# Не получается сделать callback из модуля run() потока

Tags: java, android, многопоточность, интерфейс

Имеется следующий код.
Создан интерфейс

```
public interface ScanerMessage {
    public default void msg(String msg) {}
}
```

затем переопределяем его в **MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ScanerMessage {
    private MainActivity linkThis;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        linkThis = this;
    }

    @Override
    public void mesg(String position) {
        Toast.makeText(this, position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

после создаём поток в **MainActivity**

```
sockedScanner scanner = new sockedScanner(linkThis);
```

В потоке получаем его и пытаемся обратиться к методу в **MainActivity**

```
public class sockedScanner extends Thread {
    private ScanerMessage callback;

    public sockedScanner(ScanerMessage callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
        callback.mesg("Привет!");
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run();
        callback.mesg("НЕ Привет!");
    }
}
```

**Вопрос.** Почему не получается обратиться к методу **callback.mesg** в модуле **run()**, а в конструкторе **sockedScanner** получается? И как это исправить?

Comment: Логи читали? Наверняка там написана причина. Проблема не в вызове колбека.  Под капотом `Toast.makeText()` не удаётся создать хандлер, поскольку у простого потока нет `Looper`-а. Дальше вопрос - а оно вам надо? Если да, то самое простое - перебросить вызов в UI-поток, в активности это можно так: `runOnUiThread(() -> Toast.makeText(this, position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show())`

Comment: "а оно вам надо?" Если честно, то я не знаю. Я с Андроидом и Java около недели занимаюсь и пока не очень понял как тут все устроено. Я пишу программу для считывания штрихкодов на телефон с подключаемого к нему bluetooth сканера. Создание spp соединения со сканером происходит у меня в отдельном thread и цикл считывания штрихкодов находиться там же. Мне нужно, чтобы при считывании штрихкода thread передавал его в MainActivity и там запускал метод его обработки (в том числе и взаимодействие с UI). вот я и ищу способ, как это осуществить.

Comment: Вот тут много чего можно почерпнуть: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads#java

Comment: Не спорю, документация Рулит. Но можно поконкретнее указать, что почитать? То что по ссылке я читал, но видимо не дошло или пропустил чего то.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно долго рассказывать как можно решать такую задачу и как принято сейчас это делать (по разному, на самом деле), в т.ч. в зависимости от языка.

Самый простой способ в вашем случае - всё содержимое метода в активити, который вы из другого потока вызываете обернуть вот в этот код:

```
runOnUiThread(() -> {
    //тут весь код из метода mesg, т.е. показ Toast.
    //всё, тут написанное, будет вызвано на главном потоке
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, действительно работает. Как я понимаю у меня метод run() запускался с контекстом thread (ну лил что то в этом роде), а конструктор потока с контекстом MainActivity. Поэтому и не получалось. Правильно?

Comment: А всё же. Как принято подобную задачу сейчас делать на Java? Чтобы понимать, в какую сторону читать.

Comment: Да, всё верно - в другом потоке выполняется только содержимое метода run. Конструктор же потока выполняется на том потоке, где он был вызван. Как правильно делать - долго рассказывать. Да и неоднозначно всё. Самый популярный способ в последние пару лет - писать на Kotlin и использовать его корутины. Если Java - то корпорация зла предлагает/предлагала использовать LiveData. Отдельный способ - использовать RxJava. Но всё вышеперечисленное - сложные штуки и, если вы не хотите тратить больше времени на их изучение чем на собственно разработку - вполне нормально писать как сейчас у вас сделано.

Comment: Если мой способ не сильно плохой, то я и правда не очень хочу сильно углубляться в эти методы. Я не собираюсь становиться Андроид разработчиком, мне нужно написать всего 1 или 2 приложения и то не сильно сложных. Так что тогда остановлюсь на этом. Спасибо ещё раз за советы, вы Очень помогли.